# Duplicity is arguing BackendException: ssh connection to my server:22 failed: not a valid OPENSSH private key file

Tags: ssh, duplicity

Thanks to [maybeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763862/using-volumerize-to-backup-my-docker-volumes-with-scp/45775184?noredirect=1#comment78528751_45775184), I've managed to backup my data from home to an external server. (An amazon one)
As i don't want to backup company datas to Amazon, i tried with an internal backup server.

I then used this command. (I have my own key)

```
docker run -d     --name volumerize     
-v /MyFolder/Keys/:/MyFolder/Keys/ 
-v jenkins_volume:/source:ro     
-v backup_volume:/backup     
-e 'VOLUMERIZE_SOURCE=/source' 
-e "VOLUMERIZE_TARGET=scp://myuser@mybackupserver/home/myuser/" 
-e 'VOLUMERIZE_DUPLICITY_OPTIONS=--ssh-options "-i /MyFolder/Keys/myuserkey"'  
-e 'PASSPHRASE="mypassphrase"' blacklabelops/volumerize
```

When using duplicity backup command, inside or outside the container, i have the following error

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py:200: DeprecationWarning: signer and verifier have been deprecated. Please use sign and verify instead.
  signature, ec.ECDSA(self.ecdsa_curve.hash_object())
BackendException: ssh connection to myuser@mybackupserver:22 failed: not a valid OPENSSH private key file
```

Strangely, inside or outside the volumerize container, the following is running properly.

```
ssh -i /MyFolder/Keys/myuserkey myuser@mybackupserver
key_load_public: invalid format
Enter passphrase for key '/MyFolder/Keys/myuser':
[myuser@mybackupserver ~]$
```

Editing backup file for example is giving me the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

source /etc/volumerize/stopContainers
duplicity $@ --allow-source-mismatch --archive-dir=/volumerize-cache --ssh-options "-i /MyFolder/Keys/myuserkey"  /source scp://myuser@mybackupserver/home/myuser/
source /etc/volumerize/startContainers
```

I've tried to check env variables inside the container, please find below what i have : (Note that passphrase has been added as env variable as found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/414606/duplicity-how-to-put-passphrase-in-command/414624))

```
HOSTNAME=b68f0e1a2d45
TERM=xterm
BLACKLABELOPS_HOME=/var/blacklabelops
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CREDENTIAL_FILE=/credentials/googledrive.cred
VOLUMERIZE_HOME=/etc/volumerize
VOLUMERIZE_SOURCE=/source
DOCKERIZE_VERSION=v0.5.0
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/etc/volumerize
VOLUMERIZE_TARGET=scp://myuser@mybackupserver/home/myuser/
PWD=/etc/volumerize
VOLUMERIZE_DUPLICITY_OPTIONS=--ssh-options "-i /MyFolder/Keys/myuserkey"
VOLUMERIZE_CACHE=/volumerize-cache
GPG_TTY=/dev/console
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
GOOGLE_DRIVE_SETTINGS=/credentials/cred.file
PASSPHRASE="mypassphrase"
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Regards,
pierre

Edit1 :
I tried to compare both private key file (Amazon and Company) using 
`openssl rsa -in yourkey.pem -check` and both says

```
RSA key ok
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Edit2 : 
1 . Had a look without any success at [duplicity-backendexception](https://tom.meinlschmidt.org/2014/04/24/duplicity-backendexception-ssh-connection-to-server22-failed-unknown-server/)

2. For information, Paramiko version is 2.2.1
3. Connection is successful using the following python script.

   ```
   import paramiko
   import StringIO
   f = open('/MyFolder/Keys/myuserkey','r')
   s = f.read()
   keyfile = StringIO.StringIO(s)
   mykey =   paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(keyfile,password='mypassphrase')
   ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
   ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   ssh.connect('mybackupserver',username='mouser',pkey=mykey)
   stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('uptime')
   stdout.readlines()
   ```

   [u' 12:35:27 up 3 days,  1:42,  0 users,  load average: 1.59, 3.10, 3.00\n']

Comment: Have you checked if the perm file is password protected? Password protected key files does not seem to work: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/340#issuecomment-62254267

Answer (score 0):

try the pexpect+scp:// backend (more on available ssh backends can be found in the duplicity manpage http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html ).
it uses the command line ssh binaries. maybe the error is different or more detailed there?

the error on

```
ssh -i /MyFolder/Keys/myuserkey myuser@mybackupserver
key_load_public: invalid format
```

does not seem normal. try to provide the public key in the proper format or not at all.

..ede/duply.net